# ImageButtonGestureRecognizers for custom button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, imagebutton

I have a collection view with my custom buttons.And have a function which change color of images and their background.My problem: it works with every button if I click,I want to make function which will change color and backgroundcolor of my SELECTED button.I thought maybe to make controls:CustomRoundButton.GestureRecognizers but I don`t understand how to write this function.Or maybe other function

```
            <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"      

                   SelectionMode="None">

                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                Span="3" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="0"
                       >
                              <controls:CustomRoundButton TintColor="#616161" HeightRequest="90"
                             WidthRequest="90" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                          BackgroundColor="White" ImageSource="heart" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>                             
                        </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

    ((CustomRoundButton)sender).BackgroundColor = ((Button)sender).BackgroundColor == Color.White
        ? Color.FromHex("#2979FF")
        : Color.White;
    CustomRoundButton.SetTintColor((CustomRoundButton)sender, CustomRoundButton.GetTintColor((CustomRoundButton)sender) == Color.FromHex("#616161")
        ? Color.White
        : Color.FromHex("#616161"));

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKInZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you used MVVM, you can achieve it my Command for your `controls:CustomRoundButton` .

Here is layout code.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <CollectionView  x:Name="BillView" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"      

                   SelectionMode="None">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                Span="3" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="0" >
                            <controls:CustomRoundButton  HeightRequest="90"
                             WidthRequest="90" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                          BackgroundColor="{Binding CustButtonColor}" ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Command="{ Binding BindingContext.ChangeCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=BillView} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyModelView();
        }

       
    }
```

Here is code about `MyModelView.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CollectionViewDemo
{
     public class MyModelView
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public ICommand ChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
        public MyModelView()
        {
            Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png",CustButtonColor=Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() { Image = "unheart.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });

            ChangeCommand = new Command<Car>((key) =>
            {
               
                var car = key as Car;
                if (car.Image == "heart.png")
                {
                    car.Image = "unheart.png"; car.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                }
                else
                {


                    car.Image = "heart.png";
                    car.CustButtonColor = Color.Red;
                }
               

            });
        }
    }
    public class Car: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string image;
        public string Image
        {
            set
            {
                if (image != value)
                {
                    image = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Image");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return image;
            }
        }

        Color _custButtonColor;
        public Color CustButtonColor
        {
            set
            {
                if (_custButtonColor != value)
                {
                    _custButtonColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CustButtonColor");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _custButtonColor;
            }
        }
      

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

======**Update**=======

> but can you help me that only ONE selected button change background color and color of the icon on the image?

Do you want to achieve the result following GIF?

[image]

If so, please change the code of `ChangeCommand`.

```
  ChangeCommand = new Command<Car>((key) =>
            {
                foreach (var item in Cars)
                {
                    item.Image = "unheart.png";
                    item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                }
                    var car = key as Car;
                    car.Image = "heart.png";
                    car.CustButtonColor = Color.Red;
            });
```

=======Update2=========

If you have different pictures, you can add a property called Name. we can reset  `ObservableCollection` by name, when we click the Button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CollectionViewDemo
{
     public class MyModelView
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public ICommand ChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
        public MyModelView()
        {
            Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            Cars.Add(new Car() {Name="Audio", Image = "unheart.png",CustButtonColor=Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() {Name="BMW", Image = "faded_div.jpg", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() {Name="BENZ", Image = "myIcon.png", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });
            Cars.Add(new Car() {Name="LEUX", Image = "wind.jpg", CustButtonColor = Color.Default });

           var DefaultCars= new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            DefaultCars = Cars;

            ChangeCommand = new Command<Car>((key) =>
            {
                //Rest the `ObservableCollection` by name.
                foreach (var item in Cars)
                {
                    if (item.Name.Equals("Audio"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "unheart.png";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }else if (item.Name.Equals("BMW"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "faded_div.jpg";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                    else if (item.Name.Equals("BENZ"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "myIcon.png";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                    else if (item.Name.Equals("LEUX"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "wind.jpg";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                   
                }
                var car = key as Car;
                


                    car.Image = "heart.png";
                    car.CustButtonColor = Color.Red;
              
               

            });
        }
    }
    public class Car: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        string image;
        public string Image
        {
            set
            {
                if (image != value)
                {
                    image = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Image");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return image;
            }
        }

        Color _custButtonColor;
        public Color CustButtonColor
        {
            set
            {
                if (_custButtonColor != value)
                {
                    _custButtonColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CustButtonColor");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _custButtonColor;
            }
        }
       

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

=========Update 3==============

You can set different icon for different button when you click it(set the different image by Name).

```
   ChangeCommand = new Command<Car>((key) =>
            {
                //reset the item to default image and background.
                foreach (var item in Cars)
                {
                    if (item.Name.Equals("Audio"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "unheart.png";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }else if (item.Name.Equals("BMW"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "faded_div.jpg";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                    else if (item.Name.Equals("BENZ"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "myIcon.png";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                    else if (item.Name.Equals("LEUX"))
                    {
                        item.Image = "wind.jpg";
                        item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;
                    }
                   
                }

                //set the different image by Name
                var car = key as Car;

                if (car.Name.Equals("BENZ"))
                {
                    car.Image = "sandwich.png";
                    
                }else if (car.Name.Equals("BMW"))
                {
                    car.Image = "rose.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    car.Image = "heart.png";

                }
                car.CustButtonColor = Color.Red;
              
               

            });
        }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Here is demo.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/CollectionViewDemo.zip

Comment: It is fantastic, but can you help me that only ONE selected button change background color and color of the icon on the image?

Comment: That is cool,and the last question,I have different images and I understand that item.Image = "unheart.png"; makes them the same,how  I must  use your code but with different images.I have 4 images(4 cars).For example when I click on Audi icon it change on the image "Audi"

Comment: @MariaKamenskyh I update my answer again. Please see it.

Comment: Can I only change to one image? Can I change a specific image to another specific image?
I see that you change different pictures for the heart, is it possible, for example, to change a burger for a sandwich, a flower for a rose?

Comment: Yes, you can, In the `ChangeCommand`, after reset the image, You can judge the `car.Name` , then set `car.Image = "xxx.png";` whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very ashamed of stupid questions, I'm new and I may have misunderstood, but I made the code and it does not assign a new picture to another new, but only the last car.Image = "ff"; in item.Name.Equals ("LEUX")

Comment: ChangeCommand = new Command<Car>((key) =>
            { var car = key as Car;  foreach (var item in Cars)
                {    if (item.Name.Equals("Audio"))
                    {    item.Image = "i_toyota"; item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default;  car.Image = "i_tesla";
                    }
                 ........
                    else if (item.Name.Equals("LEUX"))
                    {  item.Image = "heart";  item.CustButtonColor = Color.Default; car.Image = "ff";  } }  car.CustButtonColor = Color.Red;



            });
        }

Comment: I will update answer and my demo to you, please wait serveral minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very ashamed, thank you again

Comment: My pleasure, please see my update answer, Do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer).

Comment: IT WOKRS.That's what I wanted.THANK YOU